# How to send Firebase Analytics in widget extension ios

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics, widgetkit

Currently, my main app has send Firebase Analytics function.
But, when i add widget to my app, and want to send event when user adds wiget. Firebase analytics cannot be sent.

I have no idea. Hope someone can do this share with me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can log that user added widget from the **main** app. You just need to get info about current configurations using [`getCurrentConfigurations(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter/getcurrentconfigurations(_:)).